# An Issue with Multiple ASP:Update Panel (Both are updated)

Tags: javascript, ajax, updatepanel

I have two update panels in my aspx page. I want to show progress using javascript code. But when I click the triggered button for one specific update panel, both of the update panels are updating. I want just one to be updated when I click button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                prm.add_initializeRequest(prm_InitializeRequest);
                prm.add_endRequest(prm_EndRequest);
                function prm_InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
                    $('#loading').show("slow");
                    /*var panelProg = $get('loading');
                    panelProg.style.display = '';*/
                    $get(args._postBackElement.id).disabled = true;
                }
                function prm_EndRequest(sender, args) {
                    $('#loading').hide("slow");

                    /*var panelProg = $get('loading');

                    panelProg.style.display = 'none';*/
                    $get(sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id).disabled = false;
                }
```

above is my javascript code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateQuestions" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="descHeader" style="width: 600px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last 10 Questions"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="descContent" style="width: 600px; height: auto;">
                        <div id="loading" style="display: none; height: 60px;">
                            <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/site/process.gif" />
                        </div>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuestions" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAsk" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

above is the update panel which is wanted to be updated. 
The other update panel is in mastepage and here it is;

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uPCheckin" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlCheckIn" runat="server" CssClass="pnlCheckIn">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Where are you now ?" Font-Size="10px"
                        ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCheckIn" runat="server" ForeColor="Gray">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" WatermarkText="Type City Name"
                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtCheckIn">
                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" CompletionSetCount="4"
                        CompletionInterval="4" EnableCaching="true" Enabled="True" MinimumPrefixLength="3"
                        ServiceMethod="NewDestinationComplete" ServicePath="~/DestinationComplete.asmx"
                        TargetControlID="txtCheckIn" CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
                        CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem">
                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCheckIn" runat="server" Text="Check-In" CssClass="btnSaveChanges"
                        OnClick="btnCheckIn_Click" />
                    <br />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what i can see is that, in your update panel, UpdateMode is set to "Conditional".
This will make only that panel to be refreshed.